# 4-4-5 Accounting Periods are the Bane of my Existence

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000, accounting

We use 4-4-5 Accounting Periods.  In case you aren't familiar with this, you can find info at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4-4-5_Calendar).

To accomplish this, I created a date table with all the days for the next 10 years.  I used the script (albeit modified) found [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC%5FID=61519).

The creation script for my table is:

```
USE [RedFridayDates];
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO
CREATE TABLE [tblRedFridayAllDates] (
[DATE_ID] int NOT NULL,
[DATE] datetime NOT NULL,
[YEAR] smallint NOT NULL,
[MONTH] tinyint NOT NULL,
[DAY_OF_WEEK] tinyint NOT NULL,
[REDFRIDAY] bit NULL,
[Period] tinyint NULL,
[ForecastSales] money NULL)
ON [PRIMARY];
GO
```

The Period is my 4-4-5 "month".

I typically link my queries to it with the following template I created:

```
SELECT RED.[YEAR] as [Year],
RED.PERIOD as [RF Period],

FROM TableName
  INNER JOIN REDFRIDAYDATES..TBLREDFRIDAYALLDATES RED
          ON RED.date =
             CAST (FLOOR (CAST (TableName.Date AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
```

Most of my database usage is SQL 2000 so my dates are all datetime fields.

Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this?  Is this the best Query template I could use?  What about other ways to convert Date to Date time?  Are there faster ways to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used extracting the date part of the datetime into a persisted computed field (maybe indexed) and do all joins and searches on the computed field (date only). In effect you'd have the 2k8 new `DATE` type in pre-2k8, at the expense of 8 bytes (or even 4 bytes if you're willing to store it as `int`). The advantages is SARGability of datetimes by only date part.